# what do you call the gameplay of an application?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean, when we want to analyse the usage of a game, we’re talking about the gameplay. What are we talking about when we want to analyse the usage of an application in a similar way? I am not thinking of the user experience, but of the "gaming" experience (the journey) itself. Is there any special word for this? or any theatrical analogy?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to (1) learning the software (2) the amount of usage over a period of weeks or years (3) what happens during a single session ? I think we need more details, i.e. an actual example.

Comment: We would like to articulate a value that we keep in mind as a company. For example, "Commit to Quality", "Think Globally" or "Gameplay First". It's just that we don't make games, we make apps

Comment: I think you are saying that you want the user to find your product easy and pleasant to use. Is that correct?   For example: "Usability first"  or "Ease of use first" or "Usability is our watchword",  or "We make things easy", etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**User journey** is a term in UX (user experience) engineering that describes the route a user takes through an application or website, or more generally, the longer-term sequence of interactions a user has with a company or brand online/via social media/via apps. It's really an aspect of the user experience. Since you mention "journey", this is probably the best term (although there are a lot of other terms in UX engineering and system design).

https://uxplanet.org/a-beginners-guide-to-user-journey-mapping-bd914f4c517c
https://www.experienceux.co.uk/faqs/what-are-user-journeys/
https://www.appcues.com/blog/user-journey-map

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will accept this solution because this terminology is closest to our context.

Answer (score 3):

Always keep things as simple as possible when speaking with a diverse audience.

The gameplay aspect of any activity can be referred to as the "User experience". It's what the user experiences while interacting with the app, video game, board game (or, assembly of Ikea furniture, changing a car tire, operating the space shuttle, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the term of the "User Experience" has been so worn out that it often loses its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

suggestions:

- gamming stats
- usage stats
- retention stats
- xp stats
- total time on app
- no of days on app
- app streak
- engagement stats
- playing points
- participation points
- application stats / app stats

p.s. Analytics helps you form hypotheses, while statistics (stats) lets you test them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not exactly the context I was thinking of. Next time, I will try to formulate my question more precisely.